# How does Function class works?

Tags: javascript

I was reading through the Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide and I came across [this](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--constructor) section that mentions the following function:

```
var subtract = Function('a', 'b', 'return a - b');
```

I tested this in the Chrome debugger console by entering the line above and then entering:

```
subtract(7,3)
```

and it returned `4`. I was very surprised that it actually worked.

The style guide mentioned that it is not a good idea to do this, but it got me to thinking about this function syntax. I've never seen a function that has no body return a proper result.

How/why does this work, how long has it been around, and what are the guidelines/best practices for using it?

Comment: `'return a - b'` is the `functionBody`; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: *"how long has it been around"* At least since there very first ECMAScript spec in 1997. *"what are the guidelines/best practices for using it"* Do not use it unless you have to generate functions dynamically.

Comment: it's been around since ecma3, and it's not "not a good idea", it's a specialized tool for certain special conditions that are less common than "normal" functions. used wrongly, dynamic functions can rob performance by curtailing under-the-hood optimizations by making compiler assumptions un-trustworthy and thus avoided. on the other hand, a well-crafted dynamic function can actually improve execution speed, sometimes dramatically, like it did in mustache.js originally before they coded out the `Function` usages to make it play nice with CSP.

Comment: Although your example *works*, the correct syntax (to maintain sanity) is `new Function(...)`

Comment: @Marcus: `new ` is not needed for any core JS constructors, and indeed, it's not an object coming out the other end like `new` typically causes, so omitting it shouldn't drive you insane ;)

Comment: @dandavis - Yup, hence the "*to maintain sanity*" ;) But `new Function()` is the actual syntax. Works regardless though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a function using the [`Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) instead of the "normal" `function` syntax. Notice the capital "F".

```
var subtract = Function('a', 'b', 'return a - b');
```

Means that you define a function with parameters `a` and `b`, with body `return a - b`. It's equivalent to

```
var subtract = function (a, b) { return a - b; };
```

Typically, you want to use `new` when invoking a constructor like this, but it works just as well without it; it's just a little harder to read (for humans).

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) explanation:

> The **`Function` constructor** creates a new `Function` object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a `Function` object.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> `new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **`arg1`, `arg2`, ... `argN`**
>   Names to be used by the function as formal
>   argument names. Each must be a string that corresponds to a valid
>   JavaScript identifier or a list of such strings separated with a
>   comma; for example "x", "theValue", or "a,b".
>
> **`functionBody`**
>   A string
>   containing the JavaScript statements comprising the function
>   definition.
>
> ...
>
> Invoking the `Function` constructor as a function (without using the `new` operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't realize: 1) that was built in functionality as reflected in the fact that the 'F' is capitalized and 2) that the last argument to the Function object is the body of the function. That is interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @BarrettNashville Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: Another interesting point from the MDN: _Invoking the Function constructor as a function (without using the new operator) has the same effect as invoking it as a constructor._

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It took a few minutes. Every time I went to select the answer I got a popup saying "You can select an answer in X minutes". Never seen that before. Done now.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

In your sample,

```
var subtract = Function('a', 'b', 'return a - b');
```

`a` and `b` are arguments that will be passed to the function body, which is `return a - b`.

> The last parameter will always be the function body

So if you pass it like,

```
var subtract = Function('a', 'b');
// Reference error b is not defined
```

This sample actually equals to,

```
var subtract = Function('a, b', 'return a - b');
```

Or in other version,

```
var subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b; };
```

or

```
var subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Constructor function**

```
var subtract = Function('a', 'b', 'return a - b');
```

or

```
var subtract = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a - b');

var result = subtract(10, 5);   // result : 5
```

This is defining a Javascript function with a built-in JavaScript function **constructor** called `Function()`. This is same in result as defining **anonymous** function using **expression**:

**Anonymous function using expression:**

```
var subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b); }

var result = subtract(10, 5);   // result : 5
```

**Constructor function syntax:**

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

All arguments (strings) are optional with a required `functionBody` (string). It uses `eval()` function to evaluate strings. It returns a new function object which is used to call the function.

**Functions with constructor should be avoided as:**

1. It is slow as it uses function `eval()` to evaluate the strings
2. It is harder to debug lines within such function
3. `eval()` can execute any javascript code, hence opens the vulnerabilities